# How do you join a 'Collection' to make a string

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a `Sub` that creates a `Collection` of servers, with each server coming from a different line of a multiline textbox.

At the end of this `Sub` I want to replace the contents of the multiline textbox with text that is trimmed on each line, and with the empty lines removed. However, I'm struggling to find out how to do this with collections.

The example below yeilds this error -

> Value of type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String'.

To work around the problem I've also tried creating a temporary `List(Of String)` and adding each trimmed server to that, but I get the same error.

How can I efficiently carry out this task? Thanks.

```
Private Sub SetServers()

    Me.Servers = New Collection
    Dim arg() As String = {vbCrLf, vbLf, vbCr}

    For Each Server As String In Me.formServers.txtServers.Text.Split(arg, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        Me.Servers.Add(Server.Trim)
    Next

    Me.formServers.txtServers.Text = String.Join(vbLf, Me.Servers) <-- Error here
    Me.ServersCount = Me.Servers.Count
    Call Me.ValidateServers()

End Sub
```

Comment: It is mandatory to use a Collection? This is an old VB6 object still available for compatibility purposes. There are better tools in the Framewerk library.

Comment: `String.Join()` is used for with `string[]` data type, in order to achieve this, `Me.Servers` must be transformed as an array string

Comment: What error do you get on the join method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use that `Collection` class? This is an old VB6 class still available for compatibility purposes There are better tools for that like a `List(Of String)` that are fully integrated with the Framework library

```
Dim Servers As List(Of String) 

Private Sub SetServers()
    Me.Servers = New List(Of String)
    Dim arg() As String = {vbCrLf, vbLf, vbCr}

    For Each Server As String In Me.formServers.txtServers.Text.Split(arg, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        Server = Server.Trim
        If Not Server.Length = 0 Then Me.Servers.Add(Server)
    Next

    ' List(Of String) is accepter as parameter for the string.Join method '
    Me.formServers.txtServers.Text = String.Join(vbLf, Me.Servers)
    Me.ServersCount = Me.Servers.Count
    Call Me.ValidateServers()
End Sub
```

I would also try the suggestion from Tony Hopkinson below. It is not clear why you need to check for an empty string when you have explicitly removed the empty strings via the StringSplitOptions

```
Me.Servers = New List(Of String) (Me.formServers.txtServers.Text.Split(arg, _
                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) _
                                 .Select(Function(x) x.Trim()))
```

Forcing a Trim on the enumerable array result of Split should be enough to remove the For Each loop.

Then to join your elements separating them again with a newline it is better to use Environment.NewLine instead of the vbLf constant

Comment: Me.Servers = New List(Of String) (Me.formServers.txtServers.Text.Split(arg, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)), maybe. but other than that...

Comment: @Steve - Thanks, this works. However the `vbLf` doesn't seem to actually be separating the content on to new lines. Not technically what the question was about, but do you know how I would do that. Also, I wasn't aware that `Collection` was old - I'll look to replace it with List in my project.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - I'll have to keep the loop so that I can trim each individual line, but it's good to know I can create a `List` like that if required. Thanks.

Comment: P.s. The `If Not Server.Length = 0 Then` part was an overhang from a previous attempt, I just forgot to remove it. Well spotted!

Comment: Try Environment.NewLine instead of vblf.

Comment: Thank you one and all, your help has been very much appropriated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
...
Me.Servers = New List(of String)
...
Me.formServers.txtServers.Text = String.Join(vbLf, Me.Servers.toArray)
...
```